# Data in the qtableview's vertical header?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

Tableview use a QSqlRelationalTableModel. How can I insert data from a column in the vertical header?

Comment: What do you want to show in the vertical header?

Comment: I have a table (mysql) with 3 columns. I want show in the vertical header of the qtableview the data of one column (of the mysql table: the ID column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be subclassing the `QSqlRelationalTableModel` and overriding `headerData` method (which is responsible for showing data for headers:

```
class MyModel(QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            index = self.index(section, 0) # assuming ID is the first column
            return self.data(index, role)
        else:
            # return original headers for horizontal orientation
            return super(MyModel, self).headerData(section, orientation, role)
```

Then use this instead of `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. If you want, you can hide the `ID` column (since it'll be duplicated) in the `QTableView` with `setColumnHidden`:

```
myTableView.setColumnHidden(0, True) # again assuming ID is the first column
```